# I can't start ubuntu because I have a problem with the local server

Tags: boot, 18.04, virtualbox, xampp

I am new to this system ( Ubuntu & linux ).
At first I was using '*xampp*' and it was working fine,
Then I downloaded '*tableplus*' to try it out and when i wanted to delete it i had difficulty then it deleted. but '*xampp*' doesn't work with me any more.
Now the **whole system does not work** with me.
When I want to open Ubuntu this screen appears...

[image: This is what appears to me when I click start Ubuntu]

Comment: Please run `systemctl status mysql.service` in the terminal and [edit] your post to add the output.

Comment: VirtualBox is not Windows Subsystem for Linux, yet you added the WSL tag for this question.